# Comment rendre "hue"; ton, teinte, tonalité chromatique en contexte avec "tint", "shade" et "tone"?

Tags: sens, anglais, usage

Je consultais l'article wikipedia sur ["hue"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) et je clique sur l'[article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teinte) en français: "ton et teinte". On peut y lire entre autres:

> Le ton ou la teinte désignent sans ambiguïté la couleur perçue.

Plus d'une ambiguité subsistent néanmoins dans mon esprit. On discute plus loin dans l'article:

> On emploie quelquefois ton et teinte avec un sens plus restreint, où
>   teinte désigne la couleur indépendamment des effets de dégradé, de
>   clarté ou d'obscurité, tandis que le ton désigne les autres
>   caractères, valeur et intensité. Une teinte peut ainsi avoir plusieurs
>   tons, qui constituent une gamme; mais d'autres auteurs inversent ces
>   précisions.

(notes omises).

**Question:** Comment articule-t-on les propriétés d'ajout de blanc (*tint*), de gris (*tone*) et de noir (*shades*) avec le mot servant à désigner "hue" en français (et donc lequel choisir) ? Si je sélectionne *English* à partir de l'article en français je tombe sur ["tints and shades"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades) et non pas *hue* ?

Example :

> This is a shade made from this hue; here is a tint of the same hue; here
>   is a tone from the same hue.

[Contexte - rouge par exemple](http://www.colorhexa.com/ff0000):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En effet c'est un peu complexe.

1. **La teinte/hue** c'est un spectre lumineux sur 360°, comme un arc-en-ciel.
   Le spectre visible ne représente donc pas une couleur particulière
   pour un angle donné puisque cet angle peut être combiné avec
   d'autres caractéristiques: la saturation et la luminosité.
2. **La saturation/tint** c'est la pureté de la couleur. Un rouge saturé est un
       rouge très vif alors que dé-saturé, il tend vers le rose.

   Pour ce qui est du blanc en général, on retire simplement la
   couleur. On peut aussi obtenir du blanc en mélangeant toutes les
   couleurs.
3. Ajout de noir : **shade** ou encore on peut dire **luminosité** en français.
   L'augmenter fait en sorte que la couleur va devenir toute noire.
4. Pour ce qui est du gris : l'explication me semble peu claire mais ce
   que j'en comprends c'est que le **tone** c'est la combinaison du **shade** et
   du **tint**. En effet, diminuer la saturation et diminuer la luminosité
   donne une couleur qui tend vers le gris, mais ce n'est pas
   nécessairement la même chose qu'ajouter du gris.

**En résumé:**

- Teinte/hue : Un rouge vif qui se trouve à l'angle 360 peut avoir,
- Un niveau de luminosité/shade de 50%, ce qui donne un rouge sang moyennement foncé.
- Ou un rose si on change seulement la saturation/tint pour 50%
- ou, si on combine un **shade** de 50% et le **tint** de 50%, on obtient ... [804040](http://www.color-hex.com/color/804040)

Comment: Je me demande si pour tout rendre dans une même phrase il ne faudra pas utiliser "couleur" ironiquement pour "hue"...

Comment: cette phrase était sur la page de Wikipédia ?

Comment: Non, c'est moi qui essaie de manier les concepts dans une phrase. En utilisant "couleur", on pourrait parler de teinte, de ton et d'ombre. Ou est-ce "chroma"? C'est une réflexion.

Comment: La couleur final est le résultat de l'application a une teinte d'une combinaison d'un taux de saturation et de luminosité spécifique.

Comment: Oui, HSV/B. Mais donc, "cette couleur foncée/ombrée, cette teinte de la même couleur, ce ton provenant de la même couleur". Qqc comme ça je me dis. Merci!

Answer (score 3):

*Hue* peut être traduit en français par *coloration* (couleur pure), *tint* par *teinte* (couleur pure + blanc), *shade* par *ombre* (couleur pure + noir) et *tone* par *ton* (couleur pure + gris).

[image: Terminologie du mélange des couleurs]

Voici le résumé de colorimétrie auquel je suis parvenu, avec les noms équivalents en anglais.

## Généralités

On appelle **couleur (*colour*)** la perception de la lumière.

On appelle **lumières métamères (*metameric lights*)** deux lumières de couleur identiques et de compositions spectrales différentes.

On appelle **lumières complémentaires (*complementary lights*)** deux lumières dont le mélange est de couleur blanche.

On constate expérimentalement que toute lumière monochromatique possède une lumière complémentaire monochromatique, sauf celles de longueur d’onde comprise entre 492 nm et 567 nm (correspondant aux lumières de couleur verte) qui possèdent une lumière complémentaire dichromatique de couleur *pourpre*. Une lumière dichromatique de couleur pourpre est composée d’un mélange d’une lumière monochromatique de couleur violette et d’une lumière monochromatique de couleur rouge, les deux extrémités du spectre électromagnétique visible. On la munie conventionnellement d’une longueur d’onde *négative* égale à l’opposée de celle de sa lumière complémentaire de couleur verte.

De l’approximation de la linéarité du mélange des lumières (*lois de Grassmann*), on déduit la *loi fondamentale du mélange des lumières* :

> Toute lumière possède une lumière métamère composée d’un mélange d’une *lumière monochromatique*, ou d’une lumière dichromatique de couleur pourpre, et d’une *lumière de couleur blanche*.

## Grandeurs physiologiques

Lumière captée par l’œil humain :

- **longueur d’onde dominante (*dominant wavelength*)** : longueur d’onde de la composante monochromatique, ou de la composante dichromatique de couleur pourpre, de la lumière métamère ;
- **pureté colorimétrique (*colourimetric purity*)** : rapport de la luminance visuelle de la composante monochromatique, ou de la composante dichromatique de couleur pourpre, de la lumière métamère et de la luminance visuelle de la lumière métamère totale ;
- **luminosité (*lightness*)** : fonction puissance de la luminance visuelle.

## Grandeurs psychologiques

Lumière perçue par le cerveau humain :

- **coloration (*hue*)** : perception de la longueur d’onde dominante ;
- **saturation (*saturation*)** : perception de la pureté colorimétrique ;
- **clarté (*brightness*)** : perception de la luminosité.

## Variations de grandeurs psychologiques

Comparaison de lumières perçues par le cerveau humain :

- **nuances (*nuances*)** : couleurs de différentes colorations ;
- **tons (*tones*)** : couleurs de différentes saturations ;
- **teintes et ombres (*tints and shades*)** : couleurs de différentes clartés.

Comment: il me semblait qu'une lumière métamère était un composé de plusieurs longueurs d'ondes lumineuses différentes, mais qui s'apparentait à une couleur (genre bleu de prusse alors que la composé est de couleur bleu + verte), ce que vous dites, mais pourquoi les lumières rouges et violettes ont des comportements différents ? L'idée est la même non ?